# length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, names

I used Granger test for time series and got the error:

> d <- read.csv("Oilseeds.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
>   grangertest(PalmoilBursaMalaysia~BasisSoybeanEXW.CBOT, order=1, data=d)

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("BasisSoybeanEXW.CBOT", "PalmoilBursaMalaysia" : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

It's a link to my csv.file (Github distorted the data, so I share it via Google Drive): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TZj918zcoipdDMMXfMaROKDP4OFHMIrSe7sHdqWUXcU/edit#gid=1905487321

I am a beginner in R, so I can't fix this error. Google doesn't provide simple answers what I should do. Please, help.

Comment: it seems to be implying that what you are comparing are not of the same dimensions (there are less columns in one than the other or rows). If you want better help, create a full set of code, and use dput to drop some data in for us to look at

Comment: Thanks for reply! I edited my question and add a link to the data.